# About the suitability of a Molex connector vs AS150 for high current applications

Tags: dc, high-current, power-connector

I am currently working on a system that requires:

1. Board to board connector for high current applications.
2. This operates at approximately 44v.
3. Expected currents: 200A, with burst up to 300A
4. Expected burst duration: Few seconds (2-5s).

We've short listed a few connectors to use in this application. They are:

1. 2 pairs of AS150 connectors paralleled, modified to be mounted on a PCB
2. A single Molex EXTreme Guardian HD power connector, with 8 power pins and 30 signal pins. I intended to use 4 pins in parallel in order to meet the current requirements.

The Mouser part numbers for the Molex connectors are:

1. Male: 538-214113-0010
2. Female: 538-214115-0010

A link to the manufacturer of the AS150s: http://www.china-amass.com/product/contain/1H745Q452M8r5120

We have significant experience using the AS150 connector. Not so much the Molex power connectors. Am I missing something important, in terms of the selection of connectors for this application?

Fundamentally is it a good engineering decision to distribute a large current across multiple pins of the connector?

Additionally, for the part numbers that I've selected, are they the correct mated pair?

Primary reason for asking this is because these Molex connectors cost 10 times that of the AS 150s

Edit:

1. Continuous currents are about 34A per pin on the Molex connector (60-120s)
2. The individual Pins on the molex connectors are rated at a contact resistance of 0.4mOhm, while the AS150s are rated at 0.2mOhm

Comment: Keep in mind that the rated current per contact is often for a single contact in free air. The current inside a case will be lower. And it will be even lower if several contacts next to each other are loaded with current (because they keep heating up each other).

Comment: I wouldn't consider any connector that doesn't have a bona fide data sheet and is sourced from a company with an obvious to link to a recognized quality system.

Comment: The individual Pins on the molex connectors are rated at a contact resistance of 0.4mOhm, while the AS150s are rated at 0.2mOhm. Now i haven't made it clear that for a vast majority of the use time the current on the individual pins on the molex connector will be at 34A (60-120s). For the most part the peaks are for extremely short durations and would be symptomatic of something very seriously wrong.

Comment: Well, I can't suggest any "connector" for carrying high currents from board to board. But I want to share an experience: In an SMPS design, we moved the output capacitors to another (daughter?) board and tried a few fat a$$ connectors to carry 50A to the main board. The result was pure frustration. And we ended up with bare copper 5mm-dia rods designed for this purpose.